# Can we make an animation of two div (boxes) swapping in a semi circular path?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, jquery-animate

I want to make an animation of two div (boxes) swapping.

Like there will be many div (boxes) in a horizontal line. And we pick any two random div(boxes).
And want to swap them. but with an animation of semicircular path at the same time.

I am weak in CSS, Can anyone please help me with this animation.

Please.

Comment: Please put your code so far into your question and also describe how the two boxes are to be picked - is it the last two clicked or ....

Comment: I have not done the code.  We can swap any two box. it doesn't depends on any action like clicking on any thing like that.  Dynamically we will get the data in an array and using for loop we will find which two boxes to be swap.

Comment: So are they picked at random and is it continuous that there is swapping taking place?

Comment: yes Sir, it is to be picked at random, and swapping will take place continuously (on condition check).